# Error " generated Column cannot refer to auto-increment column " in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a Table in MySQL with `id` as `bigint not null auto_increment` . This is the structure of MySQL table

```
create table test_profile (
  id bigint not null auto_increment,
  type integer not null,
  type2 integer generated always as (case when type = 0 then id else type end),
  primary key (id),
  constraint fk_profile_to foreign key(test_profile_1) references test_profile_1(id) on delete cascade
);
```

I have run this table on MySQL workbench , I am getting the following error

```
Error Code: 3109. Generated column 'type2' cannot refer to auto-increment column.
```

Any idea to solve this type of error ? Any alternative methods or suggestions ?

Comment: Don't use the id column? The error seems pretty clear to me. You cannot reference the id column, because it's an auto increment column.

Comment: so what should i do reefer instead of id ? should i remove this ? But this is working pretty well on DB2 and PostgreSQL .  I don't know why it is failing in MySQL

Comment: Where is the foreign key field? in another table?

Comment: yes . it is in another table

Answer (score 1):

Use trigger instead to fulfill your requirement as generated column can't refer auto increment column . This is the one good alternative for performing such a task. Below is insert trigger and I think you have to create `AFTER UPDATE` trigger also

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TRGUpdateTestProfile
    AFTER INSERT ON test_profile
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
    UPDATE test_profile SET Type2 = case when type = 0 then new.id else new.type end 
    WHERE id = new.id;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this just does not work. You'll get the following error:

"Can't update table 'test_profile' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

I still don't know how to do this. I want to do it because I want to rename my auto_increment column and do so in a backwards-compatible, measured way.